# How to implement slanting image

Tags: html, css

Here is needed structure of a page http://pics.livejournal.com/ekuzmin/pic/0001wtyw

Big image should be over all elements on the page and has slanting form. Green boxes should be accessible by mouse clicking. So, you see, it's not a trivial task and it's quite difficult to find the proper solution.

The big image is moving from right to left when user clicks on a special button and can be different and set by editor in the administration module of a site.

More or less suitable solution is using MAP, but I guess it's not the best.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is the image always slanted? When is it slanted? Is it ever not slanted?

Comment: It's also unclear to me. Why is a massive slanted image covering your text?

Comment: 2Lollero: Yes, the image can be different and always slanted.

2thirtydot: It's a design feature :) Image is covered a part of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like what you're describing: http://jsfiddle.net/epDkA/? It should work in Chrome/Safari and Firefox.

If so, there's info here on how to get it working in IE: http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/cross-browser-rotation-transformation-with-css/

There's a good article on rotation with CSS here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

EDIT:

Added button to move image right to left: http://jsfiddle.net/Bu6pr/

Comment: Thanks, but initially the image should be rotated and saved to the reverse side, so, after rotation we will have normal view of picture...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean it starts at an angle, but after some event (something is clicked, or a timer), it rotates until it's at a normal orientation?

Comment: Let's see. Here is original picture: http://htmltricks.ru/stuff/original.jpg
Here is what we will have after rotation: http://htmltricks.ru/stuff/have.jpg
But we need this one: http://htmltricks.ru/stuff/need.jpg

Is it clear now? :)

Comment: That's ok - I don't always explain perfectly either. I'm just trying to get a picture. Do you mean the image is animated, and rotates as it moves across the screen?

Comment: Do you want to go from 'original.jpg' to 'need.jpg', or 'have.jpg' to 'need.jpg'?

Comment: I need to make the need.jpg from original.jpg in some way on the page. This way I want to know :)

Comment: Ok, I've created an example at http://jsfiddle.net/Bu6pr/1/ - you can click the red button to get the effect of slanting the image.

Comment: If masking it with background color is fine then i would go with the same thing except just use another image to mask.. as it will be so much more crossbrowser.

Comment: @Lollero, I think that's a better idea. The first way will work across Webkit/Gecko, but needs a complicated filter "Maxtrix" to work with IE. If someone for some reason reads this and wants to implement this kind of technique - here's a plugin to make rotation work in most modern browsers (as well as IE 6+): http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had no idea that you can do it even with ie6. though i would rather have it working cross OS and not at all in ie6 but.. You cant always win i suppose.